# Grails giving 404 for mapped Url

Tags: grails, url-mapping

I have a grails 2.3.8 app.

It has a view: views/rte/subscriptions.gsp

I have a controller: controllers/RTEController.groovy

RTEController contains an action:

```
def subscriptions() { 

}
```

UrlMappings.groovy contains:

```
    "/rte" (controller: "rte") {
        action = [GET: "subscriptions"]
    }
```

When I browse to:

```
http://localhost:8080/MYAPP/rte
```

I get a 404 error.

Why is the url mapping not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since CamelCase format is not used for controller name. The mapping has to match with the exact name of the controller. Modify the url mapping as below:

```
"/rte" (controller: "RTE") { //controller name all CAPS
    action = [GET: "subscriptions"]
}
```

Also note, this is applicable during dependency injection as well. For example, if there is a service named `RTEService`, then it can only be injected in other classes as

```
def RTEService //instead of def rteService or def rTEService
```

Comment: Or follow the usual conventions - use camel case by renaming the class `RteController`